# Adding buttons to a OSM (open street map) view OSMDroid

Tags: android, osmdroid

Can anyone tell me how to add buttons to an OSM view?

I'm making an app that will track a user's location. I just want to put start and stop buttons at the bottom of the map, but I can't figure it out.

Anyone ever done this before that can point me in the right direction?